# Draw tbitmap with scale and alpha channel faster

Tags: graphics, c++builder, tbitmap

The following code copies a large bitmap blends it with the correct background and then draws a semi transparent image with a clipped region to save draw time...  Images are in an array and prescaled...

This has been through several levels of optimization based on my limited knowledge of C++ and the Builder graphics...

**Edit:** Updated code... blend();

```cpp
void blend(Graphics::TBitmap *dst,int x,int y,Graphics::TBitmap *src,BYTE 
alpha)
{
const int n=3;          // pixel align [Bytes]
int dx0,dy0,dx1,dy1,    // dst BBOX
    sx0,sy0,sx1,sy1,    // src BBOX
    dx,dy,sx,sy,i;
BYTE *dp,*sp;
WORD a,_a,sc,dc,da[256],sa[256];

// compute BBOX (handle clipping)
dx=src->Width; dy=src->Height;
dx0=x; sx0=0; dx1=x+dx; sx1=dx;
dy0=y; sy0=0; dy1=y+dy; sy1=dy;


// blend
a=alpha; _a=255-a;
for (i=0;i<256;i++){ da[i]=_a*i; sa[i]=a*i; }   // precompute BYTE*a and 
BYTE*_a LUTs

for (dy=dy0,sy=sy0;dy<dy1;dy++,sy++)        // ScanLines
    {
    dp=(BYTE*)dst->ScanLine[dy]+(n*dx0);
    sp=(BYTE*)src->ScanLine[sy]+(n*sx0);
    for (dx=dx0,sx=sx0;dx<dx1;dx++,sx++)    // single ScanLine
     for (i=0;i<n;i++,dp++,sp++)            // RGB
      *dp=WORD((sa[*sp]+da[*dp])>>8);       // blend function
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    det1maps.push_back( new Graphics::TBitmap() );
    for (int i = 1; i < 176; i++)
    {
        det1maps.push_back( new Graphics::TBitmap() );
        det1maps[i]->SetSize(t,t);
        det1maps[i]->Canvas->StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, t, t), Det1_bmp.get()); // scale
        t = t + 24;
    }
```

//------------------EDIT 3  Current version 1/18

```
det1maps[ss]->Transparent = true;
Form1->imgTemp->Picture->Assign(layer0_bmap.get()); //why background first?
HRGN MyRgn;
MyRgn = ::CreateRectRgn(0,0,Sw,Sh);
::SelectClipRgn(Form1->imgTemp->Canvas->Handle,MyRgn); //clip

Form1->imgTemp->Canvas->Draw(X3,Y3,det1maps[ss]); // draw det

blend(layer0_bmap.get(),0,0,Form1->imgTemp->Picture->Bitmap,int(obj[index]));
```

Comment: Speed is faster, about 2x - 2.5x faster...  Any other optimizations?  how about going to 16bit?   How could that be done? This code is very impressive but again it's over my head...

Comment: You need to measure the times and let us know... also tell us the resolution you are using and number of images ... showing us the code modification  so we do not need to guess ... mine blends two 1024x768 images in 9ms on AMD A8-5500 3.2GHz  ->  250MB/s write + 500MB/s read I think that is hitting the memory through output on mine setup.... If that is not enough you need to use GPU ... without the code I can recomend only what I already did and use the scan line for background only once. If the images are static (used many times over and over) then the scan line can be read ahead for all...

Comment: Also you should determine where the bottleneck is (loading images can be slow too) and the `pixelformat` change can be also slow. Also doing this 16 bit might be slower as you need to do this on per channel basis and the bit shifts and masks for their decoding and encoding will slow down considerably

Comment: Presently the images are in an array...largest size is 3K x 3K  Tried using clipping region but no real difference. I am not advanced at C/C++ so I am probably not understanding some basics, and I'm weak on pointers.  I have to pass bmp to image control then to Blend()...  No idea how to pass from array, it fails.  Also have to write target first on src canvas then src otherwise it does something odd...no idea why.   Will keep playing with it...  trondyne@gmail

Comment: Some very odd things that are beyond my understanding...  Can't simply pass bmp...  source is stored in array like bmp[i]  .  If I try to pass that it complains about a pointer...  target has to be drawn on src first otherwise it does something crazy... No idea why...  Target is passed with a bmp.get()...  The only area that needs to be drawn is in a window much smaller than the actual graphic...  I do appreciate the code...it's far above my level however, so I'm reverse engineering a saucer...

Comment: Added new code with function...  Good luck at the dentist..!

Comment: I am back I added edit1 with bmp array and prereaded ScanLines for the array example. I removed the clipping stuff to make it more understandable so make sure x0,y0,x1-1,y1-1 are inside the image ... The alpha coeficients are stored also in array so you can have different alpha for each image in array ... Also now its blended only the rectangle area so it should be much much faster ... also I removed obsolete comments ...

Comment: Very interesting...  I will check it out later...  Very generous with the code, hard to find...  If you want to see what I do with it mail me:  trondyne@gmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here small simple **C++/VCL** `ScanLine` **Alpha Blend** example I just put together:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void blend(Graphics::TBitmap *dst,int x,int y,Graphics::TBitmap *src,BYTE alpha)
    {
    const int n=3;          // pixel align [Bytes]
    int dx0,dy0,dx1,dy1,    // dst BBOX
        sx0,sy0,sx1,sy1,    // src BBOX
        dx,dy,sx,sy,i;
    BYTE *dp,*sp;
    WORD a,_a,sc,dc,da[256],sa[256];
    // compute BBOX (handle clipping)
    dx=src->Width; dy=src->Height;
    dx0=x; sx0=0; dx1=x+dx; sx1=dx;
    dy0=y; sy0=0; dy1=y+dy; sy1=dy;
    if (dx0<0){ sx0-=dx0; dx0=0; }
    if (dy0<0){ sy0-=dy0; dy0=0; }
    dx=dst->Width; dy=dst->Height;
    if (dx1>dx){ sx1+=dx-dx1; dx1=dx; }
    if (dy1>dy){ sy1+=dy-dy1; dy1=dy; }
    // make sure config is compatible with ScanLine[]
    dst->HandleType=bmDIB; dst->PixelFormat=pf24bit;
    src->HandleType=bmDIB; src->PixelFormat=pf24bit;
    // blend
    a=alpha; _a=255-a;
    for (i=0;i<256;i++){ da[i]=_a*i; sa[i]=a*i; }   // precompite BYTE*a and BYTE*_a LUTs
    for (dy=dy0,sy=sy0;dy<dy1;dy++,sy++)        // ScanLines
        {
        dp=(BYTE*)dst->ScanLine[dy]+(n*dx0);
        sp=(BYTE*)src->ScanLine[sy]+(n*sx0);
        for (dx=dx0,sx=sx0;dx<dx1;dx++,sx++)    // single ScanLine
         for (i=0;i<n;i++,dp++,sp++)            // RGB
          *dp=WORD((sa[*sp]+da[*dp])>>8);       // blend function
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I just process the image on per pixel/channel basis and for each channel (R,G,B) compute:

```
dst_pixel =  ( src_pixel*alpha + dst_pixel*(255-alpha) )/255
```

where channels and alpha are 8 bit unsigned integers... For speed I used 24 bit pixel format (usually I use 32bit instead).

To avoid `*,/` in teh Blending I precomputed 2 **LUT**s with all posible combinations of `number*alpha` and `number*(255-alpha)`. The division is done by bit shift `>>8`.

To improve speed you can remember all `ScanLine[]` of the `dst` image into your array once and then use that as the target image will be used many times ...

When I tested this on blending 2 `1024x768` images together it took `<=9ms` on mine setup. The slowest operation is the `ScanLine[]` access, and images where formated to the pixel format prior to blending...

Here GIF preview (scaled down 1/4 and dithered by my capturer so it fits to imgur 2MByte limit):

[image: animation]

This is the code I used for this (single timer VCL App):

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "win_main.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <jpeg.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TMain *Main;
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp,*bmp0,*bmp1; // back buffer, image0, image1, ...
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void blend(Graphics::TBitmap *dst,int x,int y,Graphics::TBitmap *src,BYTE alpha)
    {
    const int n=3;          // pixel align [Bytes]
    int dx0,dy0,dx1,dy1,    // dst BBOX
        sx0,sy0,sx1,sy1,    // src BBOX
        dx,dy,sx,sy,i;
    BYTE *dp,*sp;
    WORD a,_a,sc,dc,da[256],sa[256];
    // compute BBOX (handle clipping)
    dx=src->Width; dy=src->Height;
    dx0=x; sx0=0; dx1=x+dx; sx1=dx;
    dy0=y; sy0=0; dy1=y+dy; sy1=dy;
    if (dx0<0){ sx0-=dx0; dx0=0; }
    if (dy0<0){ sy0-=dy0; dy0=0; }
    dx=dst->Width; dy=dst->Height;
    if (dx1>dx){ sx1+=dx-dx1; dx1=dx; }
    if (dy1>dy){ sy1+=dy-dy1; dy1=dy; }
    // make sure config is compatible with ScanLine[]
    dst->HandleType=bmDIB; dst->PixelFormat=pf24bit;
    src->HandleType=bmDIB; src->PixelFormat=pf24bit;
    // blend
    a=alpha; _a=255-a;
    for (i=0;i<256;i++){ da[i]=_a*i; sa[i]=a*i; }   // precompite BYTE*a and BYTE*_a LUTs
    for (dy=dy0,sy=sy0;dy<dy1;dy++,sy++)        // ScanLines
        {
        dp=(BYTE*)dst->ScanLine[dy]+(n*dx0);
        sp=(BYTE*)src->ScanLine[sy]+(n*sx0);
        for (dx=dx0,sx=sx0;dx<dx1;dx++,sx++)    // single ScanLine
         for (i=0;i<n;i++,dp++,sp++)            // RGB
          *dp=WORD((sa[*sp]+da[*dp])>>8);       // blend function
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TMain::draw()
    {
    bmp->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp0);            // render background bmp0
    static float a=0.0; a+=0.025*M_PI;
    blend(bmp,0,0,bmp1,fabs(255.0*sin(a))); // alfa blend in bmp1
    Main->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);            // show result on screen
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMain::TMain(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
    {
    // create bitmaps
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp0=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp1=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    // laod images
    TJPEGImage *jpg=new TJPEGImage;
    jpg->LoadFromFile("img0.jpg"); bmp0->Assign(jpg);
    jpg->LoadFromFile("img1.jpg"); bmp1->Assign(jpg);
    delete jpg;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // delete bitmaps
    delete bmp0;
    delete bmp1;
    delete bmp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    bmp->Width =ClientWidth;
    bmp->Height=ClientHeight;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::tim_redrawTimer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here the images (first nice 1024x768 images I found on Google images):

[image: img0]

[image: img1]

Here preview of Blending result:

[image: blend]

For more info about the **ScanLine** see:

- [gfx rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214)

If you need even more speed then you should go for **GPU** Blending (**OpenGL** or **DirectX**).

**[Edit2] array + rectangle example**

After your edited your question its now obvious:

1. **your array of bitmaps is not an array at all**

   its rather some kind of list template like `vector<Graphics::TBitmap*>` or similar... So you do not have access to linear array of the bmps like I do. To make your life easier I used mine template with similar properties so you can see how to handle those (sorry I can not share the template code but you just need to change `List<T>` into `Vector<T>` or whatever you are using ...

   This is the reason why the array pointer did not work for you as you do not have one. Its possibly your template expose it with some member. Mine does it like `map.dat` so yours might have something similar or not at all if not stored linearly.
2. **You are blending just 2 images not the whole array**

   so you can use the first example and add the ScanLine preloading as your images are static... Do the same for backbuffer image as that changes only after resize.

When I put all together here the result:

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "win_main.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <jpeg.hpp>
#include "list.h"           // mine list<T> template you got probably vector<> or something similar instead
#include "performance.h"    // this is mine tbeg/tend/tstr time measurement
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TMain *Main;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// [back buffer]
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp;             // bitmap
BYTE **bmp_pyx=NULL;                // preloaded ScanLines [y][x]
void bmp_init()                     // create preloaded ScanLines
    {
    bmp_pyx=new BYTE*[bmp->Height];
    for (int y=0;y<bmp->Height;y++)
     bmp_pyx[y]=(BYTE*)bmp->ScanLine[y];
    }
void bmp_exit()                     // release preloaded ScanLines
    {
    delete[] bmp_pyx;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// [array of images]
const AnsiString filename[]=        // filenames
    {
    "img0.jpg",
    "img1.jpg",
    "img2.jpg",
    "img3.jpg",
    "img4.jpg",
    "img5.jpg",
    "img6.jpg",
    "img7.jpg",
    "img8.jpg",
    "img9.jpg",
    ""
    };
List<Graphics::TBitmap*> map;       // your "array" of bitmaps
int maps=0;                         // number of images
BYTE ***map_pyx=NULL;               // preloaded ScanLines [ix][y][x]
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void map_init()                     // alocate and prepare data
    {
    int i,y;
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp;
    TJPEGImage *jpg=new TJPEGImage;
    // create "array" of bmp (you already got this)
    for (maps=0;filename[maps]!="";maps++)
        {
        map.add(new Graphics::TBitmap); // this is like your push_back(new Graphics::TBitmap)
        jpg->LoadFromFile(filename[maps]);  // filename[] -> jpg -> bmp -> map[]
        map[maps]->Assign(jpg);             // here you can also rescale or whatever you want to do...
        map[maps]->HandleType=bmDIB;
        map[maps]->PixelFormat=pf24bit;
        }
    // create preloaded ScanLines (you need to add this into your app init)
    map_pyx=new BYTE**[maps];                   // **map_pyx[]
    for (i=0;i<maps;i++)
        {
        map_pyx[i]=new BYTE*[map[i]->Height];   // *map_pyx[][]
        for (y=0;y<map[i]->Height;y++)          // map_pyx[][]]
         map_pyx[i][y]=(BYTE*)map[i]->ScanLine[y];
        }
    delete jpg;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void map_exit()                     // release data (you need to add this in app exit)
    {
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<maps;i++)
        {
        delete   map[i];
        delete[] map_pyx[i];
        }
    delete[] map_pyx;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void blend_rec(BYTE **dp,int x0,int y0,int x1,int y1,BYTE **sp,BYTE alpha)
    {
    const int n=3;          // pixel align [Bytes]
    int x,y,i;
    BYTE *d,*s;
    WORD da[256],sa[256];
    // pixelformat align
    x0*=n; x1*=n;
    // prepare alpha*BYTE and (255-alpha)*BYTE LUTs
    y=    alpha; for (x=0;x<256;x++) sa[x]=x*y;
    y=255-alpha; for (x=0;x<256;x++) da[x]=x*y;
    // blend
    for (y=y0;y<y1;y++)
        {
        d=dp[y]+x0;
        s=sp[y]+x0;
        for (x=x0;x<x1;x++,d++,s++)
         *d=WORD((sa[*s]+da[*d])>>8);       // blend function
        }
    // release data
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TMain::draw()
    {
    bmp->Canvas->Draw(0,0,map[0]);              // render background bmp[0]
    static float a=0.0; a+=0.025*M_PI;          // animation ...
    BYTE alpha=128+float(127.0*sin(a));
    tbeg();
    blend_rec(bmp_pyx,200,500,400,600,map_pyx[1],alpha);    // add the blended rectangle (except background which is bmp[0]
    tend(); Caption=tstr();
    Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);                      // show on screen
//  bmp->SaveToFile("out.bmp");
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMain::TMain(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
    {
    // create bitmaps
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp_init();
    map_init();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // delete bitmaps
    delete bmp;
    bmp_exit();
    map_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    bmp->Width =ClientWidth;
    bmp->Height=ClientHeight;
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf24bit;
    bmp_exit();
    bmp_init();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::tim_redrawTimer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The blending is done in less than `0.5ms` on my setup for teh rectangle I choosed. As you can see its way faster than original `9ms` ... Because if you are using cliping region you will still blend whole image just not copy the result. This approach only Blends and copy what is needed.

Beware I removed the range checks so make sure the rectangle is inside of images ...

If you want to measure the time in the same way I do I am using this code of mine:

**Performance.h:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- Performance counter time measurement: 2.01 ----------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _performance_h
#define _performance_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int   performance_max=64;                 // push urovni
double      performance_Tms=-1.0,               // perioda citaca [ms]
            performance_tms=0.0,                // zmerany cas po tend [ms]
            performance_t0[performance_max];    // zmerane start casy [ms]
int         performance_ix=-1;                  // index aktualneho casu
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tbeg(double *t0=NULL)  // mesure start time
    {
    double t;
    LARGE_INTEGER i;
    if (performance_Tms<=0.0)
        {
        for (int j=0;j<performance_max;j++) performance_t0[j]=0.0;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&i); performance_Tms=1000.0/double(i.QuadPart);
        }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&i); t=double(i.QuadPart); t*=performance_Tms;
    if (t0) { t0[0]=t; return; }
    performance_ix++;
    if ((performance_ix>=0)&&(performance_ix<performance_max)) performance_t0[performance_ix]=t;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tpause(double *t0=NULL)    // stop counting time between tbeg()..tend() calls
    {
    double t;
    LARGE_INTEGER i;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&i); t=double(i.QuadPart); t*=performance_Tms;
    if (t0) { t0[0]=t-t0[0]; return; }
    if ((performance_ix>=0)&&(performance_ix<performance_max)) performance_t0[performance_ix]=t-performance_t0[performance_ix];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tresume(double *t0=NULL)   // resume counting time between tbeg()..tend() calls
    {
    double t;
    LARGE_INTEGER i;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&i); t=double(i.QuadPart); t*=performance_Tms;
    if (t0) { t0[0]=t-t0[0]; return; }
    if ((performance_ix>=0)&&(performance_ix<performance_max)) performance_t0[performance_ix]=t-performance_t0[performance_ix];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double tend(double *t0=NULL)    // return duration [ms] between matching tbeg()..tend() calls
    {
    double t;
    LARGE_INTEGER i;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&i); t=double(i.QuadPart); t*=performance_Tms;
    if (t0) { t-=t0[0]; performance_tms=t; return t; }
    if ((performance_ix>=0)&&(performance_ix<performance_max)) t-=performance_t0[performance_ix]; else t=0.0;
    performance_ix--;
    performance_tms=t;
    return t;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double tper(double *t0=NULL)    // return duration [ms] between tper() calls
    {
    double t,tt;
    LARGE_INTEGER i;
    if (performance_Tms<=0.0)
        {
        for (int j=0;j<performance_max;j++) performance_t0[j]=0.0;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&i); performance_Tms=1000.0/double(i.QuadPart);
        }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&i); t=double(i.QuadPart); t*=performance_Tms;
    if (t0) { tt=t-t0[0]; t0[0]=t; performance_tms=tt; return tt; }
    performance_ix++;
    if ((performance_ix>=0)&&(performance_ix<performance_max))
        {
        tt=t-performance_t0[performance_ix];
        performance_t0[performance_ix]=t;
        }
    else { t=0.0; tt=0.0; };
    performance_ix--;
    performance_tms=tt;
    return tt;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnsiString tstr()
    {
    AnsiString s;
    s=s.sprintf("%8.3lf",performance_tms); while (s.Length()<8) s=" "+s; s="["+s+" ms]";
    return s;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnsiString tstr(int N)
    {
    AnsiString s;
    s=s.sprintf("%8.3lf",performance_tms/double(N)); while (s.Length()<8) s=" "+s; s="["+s+" ms]";
    return s;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186951/discussion-on-answer-by-spektre-draw-tbitmap-with-scale-and-alpha-channel-faster).